# Why can't I use LINQ in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, .net-framework-version

I'm working on an Asp.Net project.

I've .Net Framework `4.0` version.

When I want to use `Linq` in the project, I take this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Show your work also.. Are you sure you add your reference successfully?

Comment: Yes. System.Data reference and using System.Data.Linq directive are already added in project.

Comment: Error message says that all! Have you imported System.Linq ?

Comment: No, the `System.Data.Linq` assembly - do you have a reference to that? That's separate to the `System.Data` assembly.

Comment: There is no System.Linq reference.

Comment: you must be using .net 2.0 on the server so upgrade the version to 4.0 or above from web server settings.

Comment: Although I've .Net Framework 4.0, the project has .Net Framework 2.0. I changed the target .NetFramework version and the problem is solved. Thanks all of your comments.

Answer (score 6):

To use `Linq` you need to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

if this line showing error then add this to your project reference.

```
System.Core.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you fixed the problem, just in case you did not add this line into web config where other assembly's are

```xml
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```